# Change detection with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying change detection mechanism and I'm having some troubles with reactjs case.

When props are changed in a react component, this component is "rerendered" (not totally true, because of the diff algorithm, but the idea is here) .

I know that when **something** happens, react browse its internal virtual DOM to check if the new value is the same as the previous one, and rerender as needed its real component tree.

My question is : what is this **something**.

For example, using angular 2, we have zone.js that allows to catch **async stuff (button click, setTimeout etc...)** and to trigger change detection.

But for now, I don't know at all of it's triggered with reactjs.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I think it's all explained [here](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/02/react-demystified.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to imagine there are 2 things here:

- the component (COMPONENT) itself, and
- things outside of the component (OUTSIDE):

#### A change inside the COMPONENT

You need to call this.setState(), this would update the state **inside** the current component, and subsequently trigger an update (automatically call render()) of this component

#### A change from the OUTSIDE

This would trigger the props/newProps of this COMPONENT to be updated, and subsequently your component is updated by calling this.setState() inside the component (componentWillReceiveProps is a lifecycle method from React)

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // initially how the state is set to MyComponent
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: this.props.name};
  }

  // own method to be called inside MyComponent
  updateName(e) {
    const newName = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.name !== newName) {
      this.setState({name:newName});
    }
  }

  // changes from the outside
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const newName = nextProps.name;
    if (this.state.name !== newName) {
      this.setState({name:newName});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.name}
        <input type="text" 
               onChange={this.updateName.bind(this)} 
               value={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It's worth pointing out that this.setState() would automatically trigger render(), while this.state.name = 'Bob' wouldn't trigger render().

Comment: This comment at the last sums it all. +1

Answer (score 1):

You said

> when **something** happens, react browse its internal virtual DOM

that something is when a new prop is being passed or if a state gets changed. Are you asking for how react internally knows when either of these happen?

Comment: >Are you asking for how react internally knows when either of these happen? Yes, I would like to know the answer to that