# how does react detect changes in a component internally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How does a component gets to know, its props are changed so that it can re-render?

Eg:

```
function component(props){
  return <p>{this.props.childVar}</p>
}

function parentComp(){
  let parentVar = 0;

   setTimeout(()=>{
    parentVar++;
    //what happens between: after this statement is executed and till the child component is re-rendered ?
  }, 1000)
  return <component childVar={parentVar} />
}
```

Comment: I Think it could be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968978/change-detection-with-react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most important aspects of React's API is that it is declarative, and that you don't have to worry about when and how changes are being captured and handled.

Basically, each time you call [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render), a different tree of react elements is being made and React’s [diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm) will compare the old and the new tree, and will make the changes if necessary.

From a `component` point of view, the instance itself does not know about trees, changes  and updates. After all it's just a function that returns a react element based on its paramters (props) and local state (if there is any).

You can read more about it in the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

Comment: ty for answer..but I was more interested in getting an overview of what happens before react gets into its reconciliation thing.

Comment: when ever a component gets a new prop or its state changed, a call to `render` will take place.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet the child component will never re-render, because what you do is just change a local variable, and child component will never know about that. So, short answer is **component doesn't know is props changed**.

There is two reasons for component to re-render:

1. `this.setState` was called
2. A parent component re-rendered